# Using Fragments with classes in Tabs (Android)

Tags: android, class, tabs

I have completed so many tutorials on this, yet I still have not found one which has helped.  The problem is I am using Tabs (with swipe), and want each tab to load a different class (some tabs will have access to different data and databases, each tab will be completely different).  I know I need to use fragments, but the tutorials just get each fragment to display 'Tab 1', 'Tab 2', etc.  Does anybody know a tutorial which explains how to do this?  Its driving me crazy!  I´ve spent so many hours trying to figure this out.  Tks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i do it:

My MainActivity with my ViewPager:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = new Tab1Fragment();
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                fragment = new Tab2Fragment();
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                fragment = new Tab3Fragment();
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                fragment = new Tab4Fragment();
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

This loads a different fragment depending on which tab is selected. For example, if tab 2 is selected, it loads Tab2Fragment.java

Comment: Thanks for the swift feedback, but my problem was inside the class, specifically, it is impossible to extend fragment and extend activity.  Does the fragment called need to extend fragment?  Or can I just extend activity?  When I just extend fragment, my code is littered with errors.  Thanks

Comment: @JonFinlay In my example, Tab2Fragment should extend Fragment. Also, are you using Sherlock Action Bar? If your not, in my answer above, make sure it extends FragmentActivity, not SherlockFragmentActivity

Comment: thank you!  I´ll shall give it a try when i get a minute.  I wasn´t aware of FragmentActivity.  But this command: fragment = new Tab1Fragment();  will automatically call another class?  When I did it it was only accepting when I added the class into the same class.

Comment: @Vartanian Basically I want this function: return fragment = new MissionOverviewActivity(); to open another FragmentActivity in another class.